# Cocoa Touch - AVFoundation

Tags: cocoa-touch, avfoundation

Im trying to play a sound in my app using the AVAudioPlayer stored in the AVFoundation. So i drag AVfoundation into the frameworks and i get a warning stating...

`ld: warning: in /Programming/Obj-C Programs/iPhone/Awkward Cricket/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation, missing required architecture i386 in file`

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hit "copy contents to folder" (or whatever it says, I forgot and I'm too lazy to look, but it's about copying it to the directory) didn't you.  Yea, get rid of the framework, then right click the frameworks folder in xcode and hit insert(?) then existing frameworks THEN choose AVFoundation